# why my model is giving same result even after >93 accuracy ? result >> array([[1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)


training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('images',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

#Found 27659 images belonging to 3 classes.



classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, (3,3), 2, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))


classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 50,
                         epochs = 30) 

test=image.load_img("./image.png",target_size=(64,64))

test=image.img_to_array(test)

import numpy as np

test=np.expand_dims(test,axis=0)

result=classifier.predict(test)

result

# result is always same as below
#array([[1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

** why i'm getting the same answer all the time , ive increased the epoch but still same ,
why it is really happening , for 2 classes i've done but for 3 or more classes its not working
or
you can give me another code for more than 3 classes to predict 
then 
and another question is how to set label based on our directory for example

```
images---
    -----cat folder
    -----dog folder
    -----fish folder
```

but
 in the labeling it will be like [0,0,...,222] how do i know 0 is cat or dog?
**

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code with two classes (cats and dogs),i have modified your code to work in binary mode, especially last dense layer, softmax to sigmoid and the loss function to make it work.
However i could see that you can do that following improvements
1. Increasing the resolution of the image
2. Increasing the network size (both width and height)
3. Add the validation data to check the model performance.
It is always good to rely on validation accuracy rather than training accuracy. If validation accuracy is good, it means that your model might do well on test data-set.

I do not really think you need to care about labeling in this case as you might have data in the respective folders and ImageDataGenerator parses that folder structure and generates labels automatically.

Comment: it was overfitting  ,dropout helped